# How to display error message using Instafeed library

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I wanted to display a message inside a `div` tag when there is no images returned using `instafeed`. I'm using the instafeed library and checked the `instafeed.js` and I saw error messages like `No images were returned from Instagram` how can I display it in my Html?

Here's my html code

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <h4>Photos</h4>

        <div id="instafeed"></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and my javascript

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/instafeed.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: 'awesome',
            resolution: 'low_resolution',
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            userId: USER_ID,
            accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
            useHttp: true,
            template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}"/></a>'
        });

        feed.run();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my html code I added a `<p> tag` and put an `id`

```
 <p id="error"></p>
```

And then in my JS i added `error` option

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        ......
        error: function(err){
                     $('#error').text(err);
            }
    });

    feed.run();
</script>
```